# Como mostrar um input após selecionar um item em select Reactjs

Tags: react, select, input

Estou tentando fazer o campo input apareça depois de selecionar a opção em select, mas eles só aparecem individualmente.

O que eu quero fazer é quando selecione 1, mostre C1. Ao selecionar 2 mostre C1 e C2. ao selecionar 3 mostre C1, C2 e C3.

O que consegui fazer foi mostra cada campo “C” individualmente.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Calculo() {
 
  const [taxa, settaxa] = useState('');
  const [custos, setcustos] = useState('');
  const [FC1, setFC1] = useState('');
  const [FC2, setFC2] = useState('');
  const [FC3, setFC3] = useState('');


const [select,setSelect]= useState();
 
const handleCapacity=(e)=>{
 setSelect(e.target.value);
}
  return (
      <div className=''>
        
              <div className="input">
                <label>n° </label>
              <select value={select} onChange={handleCapacity}>
                    <option >1</option>
                    <option >2</option>
                    <option >3</option>

              </select>
              </div>
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">A =</label>
              <input className="lote" type="number" id='lote' required="required"value={taxa} onChange={(e)=> settaxa(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>  
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">B =</label>
              <input className="custo" type="number" id='custo' required="required" value={custos} onChange={(e)=> setcustos(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>  
            {select==="1"&& <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>}
            {select==="2"&& <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            {select==="3"&&
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div> 

        </div>
    );
}

export default Calculo
```

Answer (score -1):

Você se esqueceu de fechar as chaves em

> {select==="3"&&

e

> {select==="2"&&

O seguinte código deve resolver seu problema

```js
function Calculo() {
 
  const [taxa, settaxa] = useState('');
  const [custos, setcustos] = useState('');
  const [FC1, setFC1] = useState('');
  const [FC2, setFC2] = useState('');
  const [FC3, setFC3] = useState('');


    const [select,setSelect]= useState();
    
    const handleCapacity=(e)=>{
    setSelect(e.target.value);
    }
  return (
      <div className=''>
        
              <div className="input">
                <label>n° </label>
              <select value={select} onChange={handleCapacity}>
                    <option >1</option>
                    <option >2</option>
                    <option >3</option>

              </select>
              </div>
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">A =</label>
              <input className="lote" type="number" id='lote' required="required"value={taxa} onChange={(e)=> settaxa(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>  
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">B =</label>
              <input className="custo" type="number" id='custo' required="required" value={custos} onChange={(e)=> setcustos(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>  
            {(select==="1" || select==="2" || select==="3") && <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>}
            {(select==="2" || select==="3") && <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>}
            {select==="3" &&
            <div className="input">
              <label htmlfor="nome">C<sub>1</sub> =</label>
              <input className="fluxo1" type="number" id='fluxo1' required="required" value={FC1} onChange={(e)=> setFC1(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            }

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Verdade. Dessa forma deu certo